# Error while updating a state object in getDerivedStateFromProps() in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state, react-props

Hi I have below code where I am calling an api in componentDidMount() and updating an object into state in getDerivedStateFromProps() method. But when I am trying to read its value in render() its giving me an error as below.

> abd.filter is not a function

Below is my code snippet.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as customerActions from "../actions/CustomerAction";

class Customer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      features: [],
    };
  }

  //fetching user's features for his eligible set of actions
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(customerActions.getFeatures("custName"));
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
   //1st time no data and 2nd time have a data in state
    return { features: props.features };
  }

  render() {
    const abd = this.state.features;//I have undefined here when component render for the first time and 2nd time I have a data 
    if (abd) {
      const feat = abd.filter((source) => source.FEATURE_CODE === "abc");// error on this line as abd.filter is not a function
      let a = [];
      feat.forEach(function (obj) {
        a.push(obj.FEATURE);
      });
      console.log("a in reder", a);
    }

    return <div>Hi</div>;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    features: state.features,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Customer);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to copy the prop into state? Can you not use the prop directly?

Comment: @NicholasTower I tried that as well. But on first time render it is undefined and on 2nd time it has a values. So in that case as well I am having the same error. I want its value in one variable and then need to fetch required values in array and bind it to dropdown on page rendering.

Comment: Please show us the reducer that's in charge of this. It sounds like you've set it up so the initial value of `features` is not an array, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @NicholasTower In my reducer I had set it to object. Now I have changed it to array and it worked. Thanks for pointing it without seeing a code. Simply awesome. Thanks again.